# Converting VICAR data to TIFF

Tags: python, gdal, data, remote-sensing, gdal-translate

I want to convert the VICAR data found at [this ASU link](https://www.mars.asu.edu/data/tes_ti/)
to TIFF that I can use in ArcGIS Pro.

How am I able to do this?

Comment: It looks like the VICAR link is a dead link. VICAR is a valid GDAL raster format https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/vicar.html, if ArcGIS Pro doesn't support this data natively you can use GDAL_Translate (or QGIS raster translate) to export to a GeoTIFF.

Answer (score 2):

- Download data with the provided WMS request
  http://ms-mars.mars.asu.edu/ti16?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image/vicar&WIDTH=2880&HEIGHT=1440&SRS=JMARS:4&BBOX=0,-90,360,90&STYLES=&VERSION=1.1.1&LAYERS=TES_Thermal_Inertia_numeric
- My browser saved the file with name "ti16". Convert it into GeoTIFF with gdal_translate. For advanced options see https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html, this is a minimal command:

  `gdal_translate ti16 ti16.tif`
- Open the TIFF with ArcGIS

[image]

Comment: thank you :) is there a way that i can reproject this so that it goes from -180 to 180? right now it's 0 to 360 so i can't georeference it correctly.

Comment: I would try first to fetch the image directly from the WMS service by editing the BBOX parameter `http://ms-mars.mars.asu.edu/ti16?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image/vicar&WIDTH=2880&HEIGHT=1440&SRS=JMARS:4&BBOX=-180,-90,180,90&STYLES=&VERSION=1.1.1&LAYERS=TES_Thermal_Inertia_numeric`. Please test if it works.