# Converting map from 0 to 360 to -180 to 180

Tags: gdal, arcgis-pro, gdalwarp, mars

this is second part of [How to convert VICAR data to TIFF](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/465761).

I was able to get the VICAR data into TIFF form by using VICAR2isis to make a .cub then gdal to make a tiff. (Yes i eventually found out I could have just done it with gdal once but I didn't know yet, I'm new).

That worked, but now when I open the TIFF in ArcGIS Pro, it looks like the map is wrapped differently than other basemaps I have.
For example, this is what it should look like:
[image]

But it actually looks like this: [image]

As you can see the three volcanos in the shaded relief don't match the three volcanos in the lower image.

How can I fix this using ISIS, GDAL, python etc.?

I tried running this code but it didn't work:

`gdalwarp -t_srs MarsMOLAEQC ti16.tif ti16_2.tif -wo SOURCE=EXTRA=1000 --config CENTER_LONG 0`

Comment: gdalinfo gives me this:

Size is 2880, 1440
Origin = (-180.000000000000000,90.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.125000000000000,-0.125000000000000)
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-180.0000000,  90.0000000)
Lower Left  (-180.0000000, -90.0000000)
Upper Right ( 180.0000000,  90.0000000)
Lower Right ( 180.0000000, -90.0000000)
Center      (   0.0000000,   0.0000000)
Band 1 Block=2880x1 Type=Int32, ColorInterp=Gray
  Min=25.000 Max=602.000

Comment: mars srs can be found here: https://spatialreference.org/ref/iau2000/49910/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get `--config center_long 0` to do anything.  An alternative is to split, swap and merge.

E.g. ti16 is the orig VICAR data

```
gdal_translate -srcwin 0 0 1440 1440 -a_ullr 0 90 180 -90 ti16 ti16_right.vrt
gdal_translate -srcwin 1440 0 1440 1440 -a_ullr -180 90 0 -90 ti16 ti16_left.vrt
gdalbuildvrt ti16.vrt ti16_left.vrt ti16_right.vrt
gdal_translate ti16.vrt ti16.tif
```

[image]

Comment: you have been so helpful! thank you, just tried it and it works :D