# GDAL warp removing half of the map

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate, python-3

I am using gdal warp to transform a geotiff between espg:4326 to epsg:3857, I have successfully done this previously on similar images but with the current geotiff it doesn't seem to be working. I am doing this in python using the following code;

```
grb = gdal.Open('./tmp/WaveFile.anl')

gdal.Translate('./tmp/{}.tif'.format(nameList[i]), grb, options="-of GTiff -b " + str(i + 1))

gdal.Warp('./tmp/{}_warped.tif'.format(nameList[i]), './tmp/{}.tif'.format(nameList[i]),
                      options="-t_srs EPSG:3857 -ts 0.25 0.25")
```

To see where the problem lies I have a handy online tool (https://products.aspose.app/gis/viewer/geotiff) which generated the following images for the tiff after the translate process (first image) and then after the warp process (second image)

[image: Image after the translate process]

[image: Image after the warp process]

If anyone knows why I am losing half of the data please let me know

Comment: Is your original image between longitudes 0-360, instead of more common -180-180?

Comment: As it happens I was literally just troubleshooting this with gdalinfo and noticed it was this exact problem, do you know how I can get around this?

Comment: Maybe some old answer could help, like https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37790/reprojecting-raster-from-0-360-to-180-180-with-cutting-180-meridian-using-gdalw. Or this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/465905/converting-map-from-0-to-360-to-180-to-180.